# Entity Framework Writing Mass Data to Database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I've got a database which amongst others has two tables of data:-

**Table 1**

- ProductID
- ProductName
- ProductDescription
- IsVisible
- IsDeleted

**Table 2**
 - ProductPriceID
 - ProductID
 - LocationID
 - Price

Table 2 can hold many prices at different locations for each product in Table 1. I'm reading from a CSV file where the product details are listed in the first columns followed by 15 columns of price values for 15 locations.

I have found that with some nearly 10,000 products being imported each time, that writing this file to the database by first writing the product, and then writing a list of the 15 prices to Table 2, 10000 times over slows the import down HUGELY. It slows it down by up to 2.5x compared to 'attempting' to write in a list of 10000 products first, followed by the some 132,000 product prices. Having 2 writes to the database massively speeds up the whole process, as the lag time is incurred at the database so writing 2 times instead of 20,000 times is much easier.

I've created to lists of the Database types for each object and added the data to each and this is fine. The problem is the ProductID in Table 2. Entity Framework doesn't return this until I call

```
context.Products.Add(productList);
context.Save();
```

But at the point this is saved, the list of product prices has already been created but without the relevant ProductID values. When it saves, it crashes because of the foreign key constraint.

Is there anyway with Entity Framework to get the ProductID, that will be assigned to this product without writing each product to the database first? Minimum numbers of database calls is crucial here.

I have the option of re-parsing all the data from the file, but I'm also not keen on this, as its extra processing time. The structure of the file will not be able to be changed.

Comment: you might look at the Bulk Insert package https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/

Comment: Brilliant thanks for your advice! I'll post an answer as soon as I get somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I weighed up all the options, and it turned out the best way for us to do it, was to write all products to one list, all product prices with the known product code to another list.

We then saved the product list to the database, and then iterated through these products to bring back the ProductID against the Product Code that matched the local list, before saving the product prices list to the database.

2 saves to the database, and one call from the database, and we've cut down a 47 minute data import to 3 minutes.

Thanks for everyones help!